# Need help troubleshooting why my OpenCV Python code is not writing captured images to the correct directories

Tags: python, opencv

this code below are suppose to capture photos and save it in labels files but after capturing it created the directories but doesn't wrote any images can someone help me.

```
import cv2
import os
import time
import uuid

IMAGE_PATH = 'Tensorflow\workspace\images\collectedimages'
labels = ['rock','paper','scissor']
number_imgs = 15
for label in labels:
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(IMAGE_PATH, label), exist_ok=True)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    print('collect images for {}'.format(label))
    time.sleep(5)
    for imgnum in range(number_imgs):
        ret,frame = cap.read()
        imgname = os.path.join(IMAGE_PATH, label, label +'.'+'{}.jpg'.format(str(uuid.uuid1)))
        cv2.imwrite(imgname, frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        time.sleep(2)
    
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code ran with out raising any error but after running the code there arent any images in the directories

Comment: Print imgname right before imwrite and check whether it is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 points:

1. The path should be:

```
IMAGE_PATH = r'Tensorflow\workspace\images\collectedimages'
```

or:

```
IMAGE_PATH = 'Tensorflow\\workspace\\images\\collectedimages'
```

in Windows.
Or simply do:

```
IMAGE_PATH = 'Tensorflow/workspace/images/collectedimages'
```

2. backticks are not usual in Python code. So change to:

```
ret,frame = cap.read()
```

Stange that this gave no error ...

3. `uuid.uuid1` is a function

```
uuid.uuid1                                                              
Out[2]: <function uuid.uuid1(node=None, clock_seq=None)>
```

So it should be `uuid.uuid1()`.

Comment: well idk what IDE you use but I used Jupyter notebook and I can sent you a screenshot if you want

Comment: you mean OS (operating system) and not IDE, isn't it?

Comment: point 2 is OP clicking some button in the editor, which threw that placeholder into the post. that is to be ignored as an editing mistake.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Ah thank you for clarifying - okay then I understand. I didn't know that editors can make such thing at all when copy pasting...

Comment: @vĩnhNguyễn sorry for telling you that you lie - while it was just the editor... never encountered such copy/paste issue but probably because using jupyter notebook rarely while coding (I use rather ipython directly).

Comment: @Gwang-Jin Kim nah its ok, its kinda my fault not checking it before posting

Comment: @vĩnhNguyễn oh it was not nice of me. Accusing you. And just our programmer brain thinks the logical way down: A or B or C :P .